# Mixing Objective-c and C: How to use a C source file that lacks header file?

Tags: objective-c, c

I wan't to use some C source in my Objective-c proj but the source lacks a header file. I get a *"implicit declaration of function"* warning when building, however the app launches fine and works fine up until I try to call one of the C functions. Now that it crashes could be cause somethings wrong with the args I pass, I haven't investigated that further yet. But:

**Is there a way to get rid of the build warning?**

**Am I on the right track? Meaning that the C source will be usable even without the header file..**

---

Some background :

I'm trying to use a GPL dynamic C library in my Objective-c project (iPhone). With no C experience the C code itself is a bit to low level for me to be able to effectively use. However the C lib also contains some higher level example programs which I can understand what they are doing and I think (hope) also modify to suit my needs. This example program is just a source file fired from a shell script wrapper. No header file.

Comment: Why not just make a header file for it?

Comment: Objective C is a C superset, so any valid C is valid Objective C. refer to @pablo's answer on how to do it

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: that was my first thought actually. Tried it out yday on a hunch when very tired and got some errors so I ditched that idea. Turns out the .h file I created in Xcode had @implementation in it instead of @interface and I was too tired to notice :P

Comment: I've changed my references to "C class" to say C source etc to not further spread the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is no such thing as a **C class**.

If you mean just calling a **C function** you can add the function prototypes in your Objective-C code.

Let's say you need to call a function `f` that returns an `int` and takes a `char` parameter that is defined in your `.c` file.

In your `.m` file, where you will call the function, add the following line:

```
int f(char);
```

You will get rid of the **implicit declaration of function**.

Alternatively, you can write all function prototypes in a custom made `.h` file of your own in case you decide you need to use those functions in other compilation units as well.

Comment: Sorry bout calling it a "C class", but I said "no C experience" =) What do you say if you want to reference the file that contains the function(s)? "C implementation file"?

Comment: @Oskar Lund: correct. You can say "C source file", "C function definition file" or "C implementation file". Hope it helps.

Comment: Otherwise, Thank you. I went with creating a new header file for it and it builds without errors now. Still crashes but I'm sure that's unrelated.

Comment: I've changed my references to "C class" to say C source etc to not further spread the confusion.